# How to fix Object bluer issue in unity 2022.3.4f1. I am try many times but this problem is not fix

Tags: c#, unit-testing, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools, unity3d-editor

In this image cube was not show clearly and every game object and text were not clear in 2D and 3D both I can try clear the text in 2D and clear object in 2D to see the video on YouTube, but video was too old this cannot work and same we can try these things in 3D.

[image]

Comment: Well as long as you textmeshpro text that should be clear. As foe the cube. Has to be your camera settings as by default it is clear.  Oh and i dont think its bluer as in blue. I think you mean blurred

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.